# how to disable the email message link after first click

Tags: php

I developed a php email activation code for activate user's account after registration, what I want is that if the user click the activation link again after first time, the link will be disabled, any one could help, thanks a lot!
here is my php code:

```
  $to  =  $email;
  $subject = " Your Registration";
  $message = "Welcome to our website!\r\rThanks for completing registration at www.example.com.
   You can complete registration by clicking the following    link:\rhttp://www.example.com/verify.php?$activationKey\r\rIf this is an error, ignore this    email and you will be removed from our mailing list.\r\rRegards,\ www.example.com Team";
    $headers = 'From: noreply@ example.com' . "\r\n" .

'Reply-To: noreply@ example.com' . "\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: You need a unique, identifiable field value (`key`, `activateid`, etc.) to validate the request, and then you need to store a value that demonstrates the account was activated, followed by a check in the activate.php code to make sure it hasn't already been used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save `activation code` into the database and whenever he/she request for the activation, compare the requested activation code against the database and if it is valid then you have to `remove` that `activation code` from the database just after you set `confirm` parameter for that account.

Comment: thanks, I mean is there a way to prevent the link function so that when I click that eamil link it won't work.